# building bookworm with packer/ansible

Tags: raspberry-pi-os-bookworm

I am building bookworm with packer and ansible, I did it with bullseye before succesfully. But I read mountpoint for /boot is now /boot/firmware.

```
image_partitions {
    name         = "boot"
    type         = "c"
    start_sector = "8192"
    filesystem   = "fat"
    size         = "256M"
    mountpoint   = "/boot/firmware"
  }
```

Would this be the correct method, or should mountpoint be set to /boot?

Comment: Your mistake here was using a too general title that has not much to do with your actual question, *"Is /boot/firmware the new mount point for the first partition on bookworm?"*, which presumably anyone with a bookworm install could tell you -- except they all skipped the question because it was about "packer/ansible".